# Getting errors while using Vidyo 1)user jid missing @ in token 2)Error setting tenant resourceId vidyo

Tags: java, android, sdk, video-streaming

```
public void Start(View v) {
    vc = new VidyoConnector(videoFrame, VidyoConnector.VidyoConnectorViewStyle.VIDYO_CONNECTORVIEWSTYLE_Default, 16, "", "", 0);
   boolean value =  vc.ShowViewAt(videoFrame, 0, 0, videoFrame.getWidth(), videoFrame.getHeight());
}

public void Connect(View v) {
    String token = TOKEN;
    boolean result = vc.Connect("prod.vidyo.io", token, "DemoUser", "DemoRoom", this);
}


             I am getting these errors as soon as call goes to Connect().
```

|ERROR   |VidyoConnector |[System thread]|user jid missing @ in token:
|ERROR   |VidyoConnector |[System thread]|Error setting tenant resourceId

I have created application token on Vidyo account .
I am not getting why there is an error while creating room(ResourceId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that there is something wrong with the token. How are you creating your token?

Note that when you are creating your token, for user name - **Do not include any special characters like "@"**

(UserName + AppID + Expiraton Time)Signed by Dev Key = Token

Try out this helper website to create a token and test - 
https://vidyocreatetoken.appspot.com/

Another common issue with token is that sometimes it contains "=" sign. If you are passing it over or copying it over from a URL, you will see "%3d" instead of "=". Replace it with "=" before calling connect.